# What's a good data structure to use for this issue in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, hash, structure

So I have the following problem:

### I want to have some sort of data store that stores a type of spaceship (spaceship ID). Each spaceship has a name.

**Situation 1**

A particular type of spaceship may only be stored once in the data store. So if users try to store the following, name 1 : spaceship type 1 and name 2 : spaceship type 1 only 1 instance of spaceship type 1 will be stored in the data structure.

**Situation 2**

If a user inputs name 1 : spaceship type 1 and then name 1 : spaceship type 2, then the data structure should store only name 1 : spaceship type 2. This means that spaceship type 1 has been replaced by spaceship type 2 as they have the same name.

---

My initial approach to this issue was to use a hash map, I would hash the spaceship id, so that if two spaceship ID's were the same I would store the spaceship ID only once in the hash map and as the value I would have an array of names that mapped to the same spaceship ID. That solved situation 1.

Situation 2 is more problematic. The hash map could be quite large and I deem it inefficient to iterate over every array in every bucket in order to identify if a name has already been used in order to remove that name and potentially the spaceship ID from the hash map and add an entry with the new spaceship ID and its corresponding name.

Would a hash map be best to use in this case, or is there another data structure I could use to solve both situations. Maybe I have to create one myself. Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: HashMap seems right.  You can control the number of buckets, to help control number of collisions.  The put method of standard java HashMap handles these situations.

Comment: Sounds like a good situation for a bidirectional map. Standard Java doesn't have one, but Guava and Apache Commons both do, if you're willing to add a library.

Comment: @DBug But his problem is situation 2 or vice-versa because of his requirement.

Comment: If I were you, I would create my own data structures to match my requisites. Tipo: you can extend Map/HashMap or even List, and implement your own code, your own Comparator for example. My opinion. But you can find some libs already implemented, see Apache for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own class using two maps, like this:

```java
public final class Spaceship {
    private final int    id;
    private final String name;
    public Spaceship(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.id + ":" + this.name;
    }
}

public final class Spacedock {
    private Map<Integer, Spaceship> byId   = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, Spaceship>  byName = new TreeMap<>(); // so getSpaceships() lists ordered by name
    public boolean containsSpaceship(Spaceship spaceship) {
        Spaceship shipInDock = this.byId.get(spaceship.getId());
        return (shipInDock != null && shipInDock.getName().equals(spaceship.getName()));
    }
    public void addSpaceship(Spaceship spaceship) {
        if (! containsSpaceship(spaceship)) {
            Spaceship prevShip = this.byId.put(spaceship.getId(), spaceship);
            if (prevShip != null)
                this.byName.remove(prevShip.getName());
            prevShip = this.byName.put(spaceship.getName(), spaceship);
            if (prevShip != null)
                this.byId.remove(prevShip.getId());
        }
    }
    public void removeSpaceship(Spaceship spaceship) {
        if (containsSpaceship(spaceship)) {
            this.byId.remove(spaceship.getId());
            this.byName.remove(spaceship.getName());
        }
    }
    public Collection<Spaceship> getSpaceships() {
        return this.byName.values();
    }
    public Spaceship getById(int id) {
        return this.byId.get(id);
    }
    public Spaceship getName(String name) {
        return this.byName.get(name);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.byName.values().toString();
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
Spacedock spacedock = new Spacedock();
spacedock.addSpaceship(new Spaceship(1, "Name1"));
System.out.println(spacedock);
spacedock.addSpaceship(new Spaceship(2, "Name2"));
System.out.println(spacedock);
spacedock.addSpaceship(new Spaceship(1, "Name2"));
System.out.println(spacedock);
spacedock.addSpaceship(new Spaceship(2, "Name2"));
System.out.println(spacedock);
spacedock.addSpaceship(new Spaceship(2, "Name1"));
System.out.println(spacedock);
```

*Output*

```
[1:Name1]
[1:Name1, 2:Name2]
[1:Name2]
[2:Name2]
[2:Name1]
```

As you can see, distinct spaceships are stored, by adding a new ship with an id or name that already exists will remove existing ship(s).

---

If you're using Java 8 and don't like null values, use the new `Optional`:

```java
public Optional<Spaceship> getById(int id) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(this.byId.get(id));
}
public Optional<Spaceship> getName(String name) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(this.byName.get(name));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas, this was useful, especially in testing, I went with a slightly different solution in the end.

Answer (score 0):

A separate map would be ideal, but if you were determined to get around any 3rd-party libraries (*a decision I would disagree with, unless the purpose is to learn how to create your own `Map`*), then the easiest way to think of it is if you were to have two `Maps`

```
Map<String, String> typeToName; //if you could have multiple of the Value, it could be Set<String>
Map<String, String> nameToType;

//put "Type1", "DoubleDouble's Destroyer" in typeToName
//put "DoubleDouble's Destroyer", "Type1" in nameToType
```

if you were to add a `"Type1", "DistractionBoat"`, You'd first see if there is any `"Type1"` from `typeToName`, and remove the corresponding name from `nameToType`.

Then you'd do the reverse, check if there is a `"DistractionBoat"` in `nameToType`, and remove any corresponding `type` from `typeToName`

Then add your new spaceship, and it would replace any spaceship(s) of the same `type` *or* `name`.

There are probably a lot of improvements that can be built on top of this (*most obvious is to make it more generic and its own class*). As it is, you sacrifice memory for speed.

Comment: Thanks for your solution!